# Javascript files very slow for file operations

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I rename, add or delete a new Javascript file, the operation takes several minutes to complete. I have tried copying all the files in my project over to a fresh project and it hasn't made a difference. Although, I don't have this problem with a fresh website.

.cs files, for example, rename within a few moments.

What is it about .js files which might cause this?

EDIT:

It appears to be something to do with the _references.js file. Without it, I have no problems. With it, then the problems occur, beginning with the length of time it takes to be added to the project.

Comment: Its using GIT and integrating with Visual Studio Online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I regenerated the `_references.js` file by deleting the contents, right clicking on it and selecting "Update Javascript References".

I think I deleted a `/// <reference` type comment at the start of one of my Javascript files. Perhaps doing that confused the mechanism.